# Examples of Mitchell-Benabou language usage

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

To cite [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mitchell-B%C3%A9nabou+language):

> The Mitchell–Bénabou language, like the internal logic of any category, is a powerful way to describe various objects in a topos as if they were sets. It can be viewed as making the topos into a generalized set theory or a type theory, so that we can write and prove statements in a topos, and properties of a topos, using first order intuitionistic predicate logic.

I am interested in examples of (references to) the aforementioned process. I suppose that ideally it has to look as follows:

- A mathematical statement is converted into a formula by means of, say, Kripke-Joyal semantics. Then it is proved by purely formal means of predicate logic.
- Such an approach has a visible advantage over alternative proofs.

Comment: If you're an algebraic geometer, somebody literally wrote a book about this subject: https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf

Comment: If I remember correctly, this approach is used a lot in Bell's book "Toposes and Local Set Theories".